# give arguments to a script with eval

Tags: tcl, eval

I don't really understand how to use the `eval` arguments.
If the script I want to eval is  :

```
set myscript { puts $::argv }
```

Then I want to call my script like this :

```
eval $myscript anArgument
```

And I expect the output to be "anArgument", but instead I have :

```
can not find channel named ""
while evaluating {eval $script vvv}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke `eval`, the command concatenates all its arguments and attempts to evaluate the resulting list (or string if you will, it's the same thing here). So, first the arguments `{ puts $::argv }` and `anArgument` are concatenated into the list `{puts $::argv anArgument}`, and then the interpreter tries to evaluate that. If the value of the global variable `argv` is an empty list, the actual command invoked will be equivalent to `puts {} anArgument`. `puts` will try to use `{}` as a channel identifier to output to, fail and leave an error message.

Now, if what you wanted to do was to pass `anArgument` to `myscript` and then `eval` it as `puts anArgument`, you should instead write

```
set myscript {puts $myarg}
set myarg anArgument
eval $myscript
```

In the first line, the evaluation of `$myarg` is postponed because of the quoting braces which turn `$` into a regular text character. The variable `myarg` is then set to a value (this can happen anywhere in the code as long as it comes before the `eval`). In the third line, the script is evaluated, and at that point the argument `$myarg` is replaced by the value `anArgument`, which is then printed.

The sort of invocation you attempted is possible, but then you need to use `apply` instead of `eval`, and a closure (anonymous function) instead of a script.

```
set myfunc {myarg {puts $myarg}}
apply $myfunc anArgument
```

The global variable `argv` does *not* pass arguments to a script which is passed to `eval`: when `tclsh` or `wish` is started by the operating system, any command line arguments given are placed in `argv`, and the value is never changed during execution unless you change it yourself (don't do that, it's just confusing).

Documentation: [apply](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/apply.htm), [eval](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/eval.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

`argv` is documented [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/tclvars.htm).